# Access VBA - Run-time error '1004' - Application defined and _Global error

Tags: vba, ms-access, runtime-error

I'm strugling with the following (part of) coding..

```
'Open Excel
   Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
   xlApp.Visible = True

'Open the workbook and worksheet
   With xlApp
      Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(strFilePathSource)
      Set xlWS = xlWB.Worksheets("DataFromDB")
      With xlWS
         .Activate
         'Delete the named ranges
         On Error Resume Next
         .Names("DataRange").Delete
         .Names("DataTable").Delete
         On Error GoTo 0
         'Copy all records from the recordset
         .Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rst
         'Add fieldnames
         .Range("A1").Select
            For intX = 0 To rst.Fields.Count - 1
               .Cells(1, intX + 1) = rst.Fields(intX).Name
            Next intX
         .Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Select
         .Names.Add Name:="DataRange", RefersTo:=Selection (*1)
         .ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("DataRange"), , xlYes).Name = "Table1" (*2)
         .ListObjects("Table1").TableStyle = "TableStyleMedium2"
         .ListObjects("Table1").Name = "DataTable"
      End With
```

The first time I run the code, everything works without errors but..

When I close the workbook and let excel open and run the code again I get a Run-
time error '1004' with sub remark 'Application-defined or Object-defined error. (Code stops then on line (*1)).

When I do not close the workbook and run the code again I get a Run-time error '1004' with sub remark 'Method 'Range' of Object '_Global' Failed. (Code stops then on line (*2)).

I looked around in all types of forums and still couldn' find a solution. That's why I posted it.

Any support/help/tips would be very much appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

To create your Excel object, try:

```
  On Error Resume Next
  Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
  If xlApp Is Nothing Then
      Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
  End If
  On Error GoTo 0
```

Comment: I adjusted the coding and got now an error (when excel and the sheet are open) that the file can not be saved under the same name, which is already good as I can build in a check on that.
But when excel is open and the sheet is closed, I still get the 1004 error with 'Application-defined or Object-defined error. '